# IE10, 11でblur効果

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

IE10、11でもblur効果、またはそれに近い効果を適用することは可能でしょうか？
できれば、png画像は使いたくありません。
css filterやsvg、Javascript等で実装できる方法をご存知の方
ご教授ください。

Answer (score 2):

IE10,11が対象ということで、SVGフィルターを使い、背景画像をぼかすサンプルを作成しました。

```css
.bg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter%20id%3D%22blur%22%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation%3D%225%22%2F%3E%3C%2Ffilter%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cimage%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdummyimage.com%2F200x200%2F000%2Ffff%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20filter%3D%22url(%23blur)%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

※IE10, IE11でしか確認していません。

まず、SVGフィルタを適用した画像を用意します。
以下の場合は、SVG内で、 http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff を指定しています。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/></filter>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" width="200" height="200" filter="url(#blur)"/>
</svg>
```

つぎにこれを１行にして、

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="200" height="200"><defs><filter id="blur"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/></filter></defs><image xlink:href="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" width="200" height="200" filter="url(#blur)"/></svg>
```

それをエンコードします。（例えばencodeURIComponentなどで）

```
%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter%20id%3D%22blur%22%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation%3D%225%22%2F%3E%3C%2Ffilter%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cimage%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdummyimage.com%2F200x200%2F000%2Ffff%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20filter%3D%22url(%23blur)%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

そして、ぼかした画像を指定したい要素のbackground-imageプロパティの値にdataURI形式で指定します。

```
.bg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter%20id%3D%22blur%22%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation%3D%225%22%2F%3E%3C%2Ffilter%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cimage%20xlink%3Ahref%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdummyimage.com%2F200x200%2F000%2Ffff%22%20width%3D%22200%22%20height%3D%22200%22%20filter%3D%22url(%23blur)%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
```

また、 http://www.blurjs.com/ といった、jQueryプラグインもあります。

Answer (score 1):

以下 http://unformedbuilding.com/articles/frosted-glass-effect-with-css-and-svg/ より引用。

> 2011年の9月に CSS と SVG filter でガラスっぽい効果をつける というのを書きましたが、これは Firefox のみを対象としたものでした。
>   そこで今回はできるだけ多くのブラウザに対応したものを作ってみます。

この辺が参考になるのではないでしょうか。IE10, 11 は [CSS filter に対応していない](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter) らしいのですが、SVG filterを使う方法がありそうです。

Answer (score 1):

EaselJS(http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) のように Canvas に Filter 効果をつけることができるライブラリを使う方法はどうでしょうか。

http://www.createjs.com/Demos/EaselJS/Filters_input.html

Answer (score 0):

ベンダープレフィクスをそれぞれ設定すれば良いと思います。

```
.background.dialog {
    -webkit-filter:blur(10px);   // for Google Chrome and Safari
    -moz-filter:blur(10px);      // for Firefox
    -o-filter:blur(10px);        // for Oper
    -ms-filter:blur(10px);       // for Internet Explorer
}
```

Comment: -ms-filter は DirectX Filter であり IE10, 11 では使えません。また書式もCSS Filterとは異なるので、このサンプルコードは不適切だと考えられます。